# How to compare and search for an element in a list with a tuple inside a list SML

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I want to search in with `searchingElements` list inside each second element in tuple list and count if there are months in the list inside tuple lists as it shown in the test, I don't know if it should done by recursion, which I have no clue how to use here.

```
fun number_in_months(months : (int * int * int) list, months2 : (int * int * int) list, 
                      months3 : (int * int * int) list, searchingElements : int list) =
    

  if #2 (hd (tl months)) = (hd searchingElements)
  then
    1 
  else
    0

val test3 = number_in_months ([(2012, 2, 28), (2013, 12, 1), (2011, 3, 31), (2011, 4, 28)], [2, 3, 4]) = 3
```

I get these 2 errors that I understood later I can't compare between list and tuple list

```
(fn {1=1,...} => 1) (hd number)
  main.sml:30.2-30.30 Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload - bad instantiation]
  stdIn:2.1-2.5 Error: unbound variable or constructor: fun3
```

Comment: The fact that the code shown is very poorly formatted isn't helping. But unravelling it, I think there must be something missing here. `fun3` is never used, and is _not_ recursive.  `number_in_months` is never defined. The code shown in the error you quote is never shown before that. It will be very difficult to help you without a more complete idea of what you've tried.

Comment: Assuming that the test code was given to you, you are supposed to write a function called "number_in_months" that takes two lists, not one called "fun3" that takes four.

Comment: BTW: I suspect that one of the points of this particular exercise is that it gets very convoluted and difficult unless you divide it into subproblems that you solve by way of helper functions.

Comment: Also: the sooner you get comfortable with pattern matching, the better.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing the code in the compiler itself and was trying testing many values so i didn't give attention to code structure, but i edited the code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really misleading if we read the function code and the test as they both are not type consistent in the very first place.

If I follow the test function which is

```
val test3 = number_in_months ([(2012,2,28),(2013,12,1),(2011,3,31),(2011,4,28)],[2,3,4]) = 3
```

then the type of `number_in_months` should be

```
val number_in_months = fn: ('a * ''b * 'c) list * ''b list -> int
```

which is a pair(2-tuple) and the function which is supposed to implement the logic

```
fun fun3 (months :(int*int*int) list, months2: (int*int*int) list, months3: 
 (int*int*int) list, searchingElements: int list)
```

is actually a function with a parameter which is a 4-tuple and a mismatch is evident. Also the parameters `months2` and `months3` are not used anywhere. Plus, each of the so called `months` parameters are of type list in themselves. Furthermore, except for the `test3` line, there isn't anything which is quite meaningful to come-up with an answer or even a reply.

However, following the **`test3`** line, I have attempted to write a function that at least gets the thing done and is as follows:

```
fun number_in_months (date_triples, months) =
    let
      fun is_second_of_any_triple ele = List.exists (fn (_, x, _) => x = ele)
    in
      List.foldl (fn (curr, acc) => if is_second_of_any_triple curr date_triples then acc + 1 else acc) 0 months
    end
```

Comment: Write a function number_in_months that takes a list of dates and a list of months (i.e., an int list) and returns the number of dates in the list of dates that are in any of the months in the list of months.Assume the list of months has no number repeated.

Comment: this's specifically what the program should be, i'm just doubting about if there will be more than 3 tuple list in the test case and how to check if the month of the tuple list is exist in the list and iterate for each element in the list, i didn't other parameters because it will be silly to don't to check elements manually

Comment: The function which I have written should work for any input which is of the form as per your test3 line. The problem is, the function definition and the function application are not in type agreement, and will always fail. Definition expects 4-tuple but the application is 2-tuple. Share some test case which will fail with the above function which I have written.,and then may be I can help some more as that should help me understand your problem better.

Comment: it's working perfectly, May i ask you if there is another primitive way to solve this?
it's a little bit complicated to me due to these things in the code didn't see before at the same there many problems looks like number_in_months problem

Comment: it's very sophisticated code but in the course i didn't see such code before so i just wondering if there is another solution also with recursion and thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks a lot for accepting it as an answer and glad to know that it works for your case. Before I could see this, already @molbdnilo has provided a recursive solution to the problem. You can refer to it as well. Let me explain the bit that I have written and hopefully that should help you going further. The is_second_of_any_triple function is lexically scoped function which only will be accessible inside the scope of our number_in_months function and not outside of it. Alternatively, we refer such functions as local bindings and are accessible only within the scope in which they are defined.

Comment: List.* functions which I have used are available natively as they are pre-loaded for us to consume. List.exists scans through a list, executing a predicate function over every element of a list and returning the very first occurrence which returns true. List.foldl is a fold left aka reduce aka aggregate etc etc.. and which takes a list and produces a single value which we call accumulated value as well, by applying an accumulator function over every element of the list, and passing over the result of the accumulator function from the previous application to the subsequent one.

Comment: I also have used "fn" expression, which is a way to create anonymous functions. We could very well have defined a named function instead and would have passed it around. But that's a choice offered by the language and we can play with it. The other thing that is used is pattern-matching construct to access the 2 element of the triplet, instead of the usual '#' way. Hope this things help you understand it better, and if not... feel free to ask. Will be glad to help you.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for re-discuss this again, what do you suggest from resources in ML(whether books or videos in depth) to able to solve such problems, because i'm taking a MOOC course have many assignments of these and the course is really super facial compared to the assignments.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry at all... Learning is very very much a subjective affair, and one must always drive it according to their convenience. Different people learn different ways, but almost always not one source is sufficient. You gotta have books, blogs, practices, problems, designing, discussions etc etc at your disposal. I suggest if its your first programming language course, don't haste. Spend good time, and understand things one by one, even though it requires you to explore through a number of sources for the same topic.

Comment: [Programming In StandardML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/isml/book.pdf), that is one of the many books that I have, and which also is only ~300 pages. This helps me go through the basic usages of things in sml. Plus, a lot of programming simple things. Never go out for complex things while learning. They only distract, derail, and disturb you from the focus.

Comment: Build a list of key concepts offered by the language, and then explore each one of them... independently first, and then in tandem with others. But, please be patient, and don't give-up(the most important part).

Comment: And never hesitate to Ask. Remember, you are learning.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A version with explicit recursion:

Suppose we had a function that counted the occurrences of a single number in a list of tuples;

```
month_occurrences: ((int * int * int) list * int) -> int
```

Then we could recurse over the list of numbers, just adding as we go along:

```
fun number_in_months(dates, []) = 0
  | number_in_months(dates, m::ms) = month_occurrences(dates, m) + number_in_months(dates, ms)
```

And `month_occurrences` with a straight recursion might look like

```
fun month_occurrences([], _) = 0
  | month_occurrences((_, m, _)::ds, m') = (if m = m' then 1 else 0) + month_occurrences(ds, m')
```

Comment: it works as well, may i ask how we define dates then later we define them as list of tuples

Comment: If you're asking about the `dates` parameter for the first function, an identifier is a pattern that matches anything, so it can match against a list of tuples. (And the "two" arguments is actually just one, which is a pair that is pattern-matched.)